# Twitter API 1.1 how to fetch details of friends

Tags: java, twitter

I have written a program to fetch the profile information for users.,Using Twitter API 1.1
When multiple user id as are given by comma separated the following error occurs

{"errors":[{"message":"Could not authenticate you","code":32}]}

The code is given below

```
package com.demo.twitter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.UUID;

import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.http.HttpException;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpRequestInterceptor;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpVersion;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.DefaultHttpClientConnection;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpProtocolParams;
import org.apache.http.params.SyncBasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.ExecutionContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpProcessor;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor;
import org.apache.http.protocol.ImmutableHttpProcessor;
import org.apache.http.protocol.RequestConnControl;
import org.apache.http.protocol.RequestContent;
import org.apache.http.protocol.RequestExpectContinue;
import org.apache.http.protocol.RequestTargetHost;
import org.apache.http.protocol.RequestUserAgent;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.demo.fb.RESTWebInvoke;



public class CrawlTwitterUserDetails
{

    private static String encode(String value)
    {
            String encoded = null;
            try {
                encoded = URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ignore) {
            }
            StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(encoded.length());
            char focus;
            for (int i = 0; i < encoded.length(); i++) {
                focus = encoded.charAt(i);
                if (focus == '*') {
                    buf.append("%2A");
                } else if (focus == '+') {
                    buf.append("%20");
                } else if (focus == '%' && (i + 1) < encoded.length()
                        && encoded.charAt(i + 1) == '7' && encoded.charAt(i + 2) == 'E') {
                    buf.append('~');
                    i += 2;
                } else {
                    buf.append(focus);
                }
            }
            return buf.toString();
        }
    private static String computeSignature(String baseString, String keyString) throws GeneralSecurityException, UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
    SecretKey secretKey = null;

    byte[] keyBytes = keyString.getBytes();
    secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "HmacSHA1");

    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
    mac.init(secretKey);

    byte[] text = baseString.getBytes();

    return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(mac.doFinal(text))).trim();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String oauth_token = "xxxxxxxxxx";
        String oauth_token_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

        JSONObject jsonresponse = new JSONObject();



        // generate authorization header
        String get_or_post = "GET";
        String oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1";

        String uuid_string = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        uuid_string = uuid_string.replaceAll("-", "");
        String oauth_nonce = uuid_string; // any relatively random alphanumeric string will work here

        // get the timestamp
        Calendar tempcal = Calendar.getInstance();
        long ts = tempcal.getTimeInMillis();// get current time in milliseconds
        String oauth_timestamp = (new Long(ts/1000)).toString(); // then divide by 1000 to get seconds

        // the parameter string must be in alphabetical order, "text" parameter added at end
        String parameter_string = "oauth_consumer_key=" + "PWf1xDrJTqwZ99uHwMNrww" + "&oauth_nonce=" + oauth_nonce + "&oauth_signature_method=" + oauth_signature_method +
        "&oauth_timestamp=" + oauth_timestamp + "&oauth_token=" + encode(oauth_token) + "&oauth_version=1.0&user_id="+encode("74663822")+encode(",")+encode("262131890");
        System.out.println("parameter_string=" + parameter_string);

        String twitter_endpoint = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json";
        String twitter_endpoint_host = "api.twitter.com";
        String twitter_endpoint_path = "/1.1/users/lookup.json";
        String signature_base_string = get_or_post + "&"+ encode(twitter_endpoint) + "&" + encode(parameter_string);
        System.out.println("signature_base_string=" + signature_base_string);
        String oauth_signature = "";
        try {
        oauth_signature = computeSignature(signature_base_string, "ZxD5KKf624TDxwrhg92QdpXjXJYu6w02EYr2PNEDAI" + "&" + encode(oauth_token_secret));
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String authorization_header_string = "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"" + "PWf1xDrJTqwZ99uHwMNrww" + "\",oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\",oauth_timestamp=\"" + oauth_timestamp +
        "\",oauth_nonce=\"" + oauth_nonce + "\",oauth_version=\"1.0\",oauth_signature=\"" + encode(oauth_signature) + "\",oauth_token=\"" + encode(oauth_token) + "\"";

        System.out.println("authorization_header_string=" + authorization_header_string);

       RESTWebInvoke followers = new RESTWebInvoke(twitter_endpoint, false);    
       HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
       params.put("user_id", encode("74663822")+URLDecoder.decode(",")+encode("262131890"));

        HashMap<String, String> header = new HashMap<String, String>();
        header.put("Authorization", authorization_header_string);
        String response = null;
        JSONObject tmp = null;
        try
        {

                response = followers.webGet("", params, header);
                System.out.println(response);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e); 
        }




}
```

}

Comment: I'm assuming you x'd out oauth_token and oauth_token_secret only for this question and they have real values in your program?

Comment: I have replaced the actual values with xxxx for posting here

Comment: You will get the above error message only when your Authentication credentials are incorrect

Comment: It is not related to authentication credentials,when I give a single user id it gives the details,but when multiple user ids are given as comma separated this error message is reproduced.